# Count of active listeners on the webclient

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Opening multiple `db.xx.onSnapshot` listeners, is there a way to know how many/what active listeners from the firebase SDK? & if there is global disconnect method to all active listeners?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Firestore doesn't have the concept of a presence system. If you need something like that, have a look at the [building a presence system](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence) page in the documentation, which describes how to use the Firebase Realtime Database for that.

Comment: Seems like a temporary work around for the presence system. I am more interested in the active listeners at any point, not caring about the state of firestore itself. Just want to know if some are hooked using the SDK or should I maintain my own solution for it?

Comment: "Cloud Firestore doesn't have the concept of a presence system." So you'll have to create your own solution. The page I linked shows one possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but I needed to do this as well, so this is what I ended up doing:

```js
export default new class FirebaseUtils {

    /** Number of active listeners */
    listenerCount = 0

    /** Wrap a canceller returned by onSnapshot() */
    wrap(canceller) {

        // Increase count
        this.listenerCount += 1

        // Wrap canceller
        let hasCancelled = false
        return e => {

            // Only do once
            if (hasCancelled) return
            hasCancelled = true

            // Cancel it
            canceller()

            // Decrease count
            this.listenerCount -= 1

        }

    }

}
```

... and then simply putting `FirebaseUtils.wrap(...)` around each and every `onSnapshot()` listener in the app. Then, to get the number of listeners at any time, you can read `FirebaseUtils.listenerCount`

Comment: Note, this is only counting the number of times your application code calls `onSnapshot()`. It doesn't necessarily reflect the actual number of live listeners that the Firestore SDK has active.

Unfortunately, I think we need the SDK itself to expose its internals for us to get an accurate count.