# How to get number of Firestore listeners distributed between Different Apps on Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

On the Firebase Console, we get the Total Number of Listeners for the Day for all collections for all the Apps. Is there a way to such that I can check the Count of Listeners distributed against Apps?
I need this data since the Firestore Implementation had been done for one of our apps quite some time back and has been stable, and we want to integrate Firestore in another platform and want to track the stability and the Listeners count will help in identifying whether the listeners are the getting created and deleted correctly or not. Since both the apps are under the same Firebase Project, so currently the count which is displayed is a culmiation of both.

Comment: Have look at this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49367239/count-of-active-listeners-on-the-webclient) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70571683/is-there-a-way-to-count-how-many-firestore-onsnapshot-are-active-in-my-app)

Comment: The Firestore console doesn't distinguish between connections from different apps in your project. You could consider using Google Analytics for tracking how many instances of each app are active, if you can extrapolate the listener count from that. If that's not possible, you'll unfortunately have to roll your own and have each client report that data to your backend in your own application code.